# Creating database in SQL Server Express using SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, smo

I'm trying to create a database in SQL Server Express using WinForms and C#

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server srv = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server srvServer();
int i = srv.Databases.Count;
```

just to get the count at the start. But I get the error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
>   Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) this is the stack track
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.Connect()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.get_ServerVersion()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.GetServerVersion()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.GetDbComparer(Boolean
>   inServer)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.InitializeStringComparer()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.AbstractCollectionBase.get_StringComparer()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SimpleObjectCollectionBase.InitInnerCollection()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.get_InternalStorage()
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.InitializeChildCollection(Boolean
>   refresh)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SmoCollectionBase.get_Count()
>   at CreateDB.CreateDB.btnCreateDB_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Guest1\Downloads\CreateDB\CreateDB\CreateDB.cs:line 82

What should be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server **Express**, and you've installed with all the defaults, then your server instance will be called `.\SQLEXPRESS`. You need to use that in your code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

Server srv = new Server(".\\SQLExpress");
int i = srv.Databases.Count;
```

If you create a new `Server` instance without specifying an instance name, it tries to connect to the **default instance** (with no name) - which you don't have, if you've installed just SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 3):

First make the connection by using the `SqlConnection` object. you should do this

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
int i = server.Databases.Count;
```